# What's different about biblical fig trees?

Tags: fruit-trees

I received a fruit tree order, and noticed that one was a "biblical fig", what is different about this one compared to the Chicago fig since both are hardy?

Comment: Maybe a Smyrna fig? Which needs a cross-polinator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_fig#Modern

Comment: those aren't hardy to zone 5ish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing so far as I am aware; biblical fig seems to refer to common fig, *Ficus carica*, (of which there are several varieties) see here  [https://ww2.odu.edu/~lmusselm/plant/bible/commonfig.php](https://ww2.odu.edu/%7Elmusselm/plant/bible/commonfig.php). Quite why your supplier labelled it 'biblical fig' is a bit of a curiousity, unless that plant is not any particular variety of *Ficus carica*.